# Outlook WebAddin Office.js taskpanel inside contact

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

With Office WebAddins, specific Outlook WebAddin, in manifest is possible to define taskpanel or button inside Contact? As i how in documentation is only in email read, compose and appointment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently web add-ins work under mail and appointment items only. See [Outlook add-in manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/manifests) for more information.

If you need to get a greater extensibility model in Outlook you may consider creating a VSTO based add-in with a custom ribbon UI, see [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20new%20Outlook%20project%20in%20Visual%20Studio&text=In%20the%20templates%20pane%2C%20expand,Outlook%20VSTO%20Add%2Din%20project.).

Comment: Thanks, @Eugene Astafiev for pointing out the needed articles.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT my pleasure!